# "river and water fronts" or "riverfront and waterfront"?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm describing situations where urban space meet water bodies. Is it correct if I generalize as "river and water frontS" or more proper to write "riverfronts and waterfronts". The first one is closer to the french and latin construction and I'm not confident it's proper English...
Thanks heaps anyways !

Answer (score 1):

It would seem simplest to just talk about "waterfronts", since "riverfronts" are a type of waterfront. It may be best to just cut the word "riverfront" completely.

Both "riverfront" (as a single compound word) and "river front" (with a attributive noun) are used, though "riverfront" seems more common. So if you decide to use both, you can write "river and water fronts, or "riverfronts and waterfronts".  But I prefer the second spelling.

Answer (score 1):

Either option would be an aceptable construction in English. "River and water fronts" is actually an *implied* type of [parallel construction](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/parallelconstruction), where instead of paralleling a tense or gerund ending, you parallel the word ending of "fronts"... except because making parallel constructions is so common in English, you can actually drop the first "front" and leave it implied.

Of course, you don't *have* to leave it implied, and spelling out "riverfronts and waterfronts" is also perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Adding a comment to my answer, because there's one thing I'm not actually 100% sure about: would it be better to write "river and water fronts" or "river and waterfronts"?  Spoken, there's no difference.  I feel like "river and waterfronts" is correct, but I'm just not sure this time.